# How to flatten multiple nested json and convert to dataframe?

Tags: json, pandas, list, nested-lists

I am trying to convert JSON (from AirTable) to dataframe that I can use for further data transform.

I ran into issue after I convert the JSON to dataframe that **one of the value in the column has nested list.**

This is sample dataframe after I flatten out w/o realizing that **"Package"** contains a nested list from its original JSON list.

```
|                    | Name                 |Source                                     |
| -------------------| ---------------------|-------------------------------------------|
|rec2mxAycpaC93jfz   | Luis Downes          |[Canceled - Lv1]                           |
|recIQ0HfCmRhUclti   | Milana Whitehouse    |[Canceled - Lv1,2019 - Lv2,2020 - Lv1]     |
|recOFVz0eajFblTzL   | Fatma Mayo           |[Canceled - Lv1,2019 - Lv4,2020 - Lv2]     |
```

This is sample JSON, the **package** is the data field that has a nested list and I would like to flatten it out.

```
[{'id': 'rec2mxAycpaC93jfz',
 'fields': {'Name': 'Luis Downes',
             'Package': ['Canceled - Lv1']},
 'createdTime': '2017-08-25T17:05:45.000Z'},
{'id': 'recIQ0HfCmRhUclti',
 'fields': {'Name': 'Milana Whitehouse',
             Package': ['Canceled - Lv1', '2019 - Lv2', '2020 - Lv1']},
 'createdTime': '2017-08-25T17:05:46.000Z'},
{'id': 'recOFVz0eajFblTzL',
 'fields': {'Name': 'Fatma Mayo',
            Package': ['Canceled - Lv1', '2019 - Lv4', '2020 - Lv2']},
 'createdTime': '2017-08-25T17:05:47.000Z'}]
]
```

Any idea on how to flat the entire JSON? I have tried couple solutions I found, including [this one](https://towardsdatascience.com/flattening-json-objects-in-python-f5343c794b10) **but it only flatten the first record into single line.**

```
# flattening JSON objects of arbitrary structure

def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}

    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(y)
    return out
```

The end result(either JSON or dataframe) I want to achieve is listed below

```
|                    | Name                 |Package- Canceled - Lv1 |Package- 2019 - Lv2 |Package- 2020 - Lv1 |Package- 2019 - Lv4 |Package- 2020 - Lv2 |                                          |
| -------------------| ---------------------|------------------------|--------------------|--------------------|--------------------|--------------------|
|rec2mxAycpaC93jfz   | Luis Downes          |1                       |0                   |0                   |0                   |0                   |
|recIQ0HfCmRhUclti   | Milana Whitehouse    |1                       |1                   |1                   |0                   |0                   |
|recOFVz0eajFblTzL   | Fatma Mayo           |1                       |0                   |0                   |1                   |1                   |
```

Thank you in advance for your help here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via `json_normalize()` and `get_dummies()`:

```
d = [{'id': 'rec2mxAycpaC93jfz',
 'fields': {'Name': 'Luis Downes',
             'Package': ['Canceled - Lv1']},
 'createdTime': '2017-08-25T17:05:45.000Z'},
{'id': 'recIQ0HfCmRhUclti',
 'fields': {'Name': 'Milana Whitehouse',
             'Package': ['Canceled - Lv1', '2019 - Lv2', '2020 - Lv1']},
 'createdTime': '2017-08-25T17:05:46.000Z'},
{'id': 'recOFVz0eajFblTzL',
 'fields': {'Name': 'Fatma Mayo',
            'Package': ['Canceled - Lv1', '2019 - Lv4', '2020 - Lv2']},
 'createdTime': '2017-08-25T17:05:47.000Z'}
]
 
df = pd.json_normalize(d)
dm = pd.get_dummies(df['fields.Package'].apply(pd.Series).stack()).sum(level=0)
pd.concat([df[['id','fields.Name']],dm], axis=1) 

                  id        fields.Name  2019 - Lv2  2019 - Lv4  2020 - Lv1  \
0  rec2mxAycpaC93jfz        Luis Downes           0           0           0   
1  recIQ0HfCmRhUclti  Milana Whitehouse           1           0           1   
2  recOFVz0eajFblTzL         Fatma Mayo           0           1           0   

   2020 - Lv2  Canceled - Lv1  
0           0               1  
1           0               1  
2           1               1
```